# When sending a file with a post request to dotcloud I get error: 413 Request Entity Too Large

Tags: python, django, dotcloud

I've written a simple django app for dotcloud which is intended to manipulate files sent to it using a post request. I've tested this locally and it seems to work fine, however I've just deployed the app and testing it by posting a 1.7MB pdf file kicked up the following error:

```
413 Request Entity Too Large
```

What are the limits in size for a post request? I'm intending on sending files of this size and potentially larger - is there a better way / a way that will work without encountering an error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [default limit for nginx](http://docs.dotcloud.com/guides/nginx/#increase-http-post-max-size).

> ### Increase HTTP POST Max Size
>
> By default, HTTP POST requests are limited to a body size of 1 MiB.
>
> You can configure it using the following directive:
>
> ```
> client_max_body_size 10m;
> ```
>
> Note that our HTTP gateways enforce a limit of 100 MiB.

Comment: This isn't specific to DotCloud. It's the Nginx default.

Comment: @MarkLavin Updated to be more general then. :)

Comment: Awesome - totally didn't know about nginx before. Thank you so much.